# Combine content for multiple markers in one infobox in google maps through Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am working with google map in asp.net with Sql Server 2008. I have multiple records for same Latitude and Longitude. Instead of showing too many pins , I would like to display one pin and in the infobox above the pin to display the content from those multiple records.

Here is my Javascript Code :

```
window.onload = function () {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
            var data = markers[i]
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: myLatlng,
                map: map,
                icon: 'marker.png',
                title: data.title,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });
            (function (marker, data) {
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent('<div style="width:250px;height:80px;background:red">' + data.description + '</div>');
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });
            })(marker, data);
        }
    }
```

Here is Asp.NET Code:

```
var markers = [
    <asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
                {
                "title": '<%# Eval("Component") %>',
                "lat": '<%# Eval("Latitude") %>',
                "lng": '<%# Eval("Longitude") %>',
                "description": '<%# Eval("Component") %>'+" "+'<%# Eval("Project_No") %>'
            }
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SeparatorTemplate>
        ,
    </SeparatorTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
    ];

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {
                DataTable dt = this.GetData("graphrepresentation");

                rptMarkers.DataSource = dt;
                rptMarkers.DataBind();
            }
        }
            private DataTable GetData(string query)
            {
                    string conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("year",0);
                    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                    {
                        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                        {
                                cmd.Connection = con;
                                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                                {
                                    sda.Fill(dt);
                                    return dt;
                                }
                        }
                    }

            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I just added the following to my script and it works.

```
var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);
    googleSingleMarkers={};
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++){
        (function (data) {
            var myLatlng  = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat,data.lng);
            hash      = myLatlng.toUrlValue();
            infoContent = '<div>'  + data.description + '</div>';
            if(typeof googleSingleMarkers[hash]==='undefined'){
                googleSingleMarkers[hash] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: myLatlng,
                    map: map,
                    title: data.title,
                    icon: 'marker.png',
                    description:data.description,
                    infoContent:infoContent,
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
            });
            google.maps.event.addListener(googleSingleMarkers[hash], "click", 
            function (e) {                  
                infoWindow.setContent(this.get('infoContent'));            
                infoWindow.open(map, this);
            });
            }else{
                googleSingleMarkers[hash].infoContent+=infoContent;
            }
    })(markers[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As you're looping over the markers, store each marker in an array.

Before you create each marker, check the array to make sure there isn't already a marker at these coordinates.

If there is, update the description (or add a new value) of the marker in the array to include the description of this duplicate location.

PS, this is not *'Javascript code'*: `<asp:Repeater ID="rptMarkers" runat="server">`

Comment: I tried doing everything but still i have problem. plz help me !

Comment: what kind of problem?

Comment: My problem is that, I have multiple records in database for same location. So, i am getting multiple marker with there infowindow on same location but i want single infowindow with multiple records. how i do that?